# Python 2 raw_input to list type

Tags: python-2.7, list, input, raw-input

I used input() in my program, to convert the input into a list type, but I read that I should use raw_input() instead.

I'm trying to let the user input vectors in the form (4,4),(2,5),(1,6)
Using input() it worked.

I used:

```
vectors = list(input('enter vectors\n'))
```

after  changing it to raw_input() I get a list with all elements in the str

```
'(' '4' ',' '4' ')' ',' '(' '2' ',' '5' ')' ',' '(' '1' ',' '6' ')'
```

How can I get the input converted to a list I would get as if I used input()?
Should I just go back to using input() instead?

Comment: What output u should get??

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a string. Doing `list` on a `str` creates a character list which is what you are getting.

Comment: Just use input().

Comment: a list like vectors = [(4,4),(2,5),(1,6)]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you input your data in form `1,2` this could do your work:

```
vectors = []
print ('enter vectors')
while True:
    a = raw_input('')
    if a == 'q':
        break
    else:
        vectors.append(tuple(int(c) for c in a.split(',')))

print vectors
```

Answer (score 0):

You were right to switch to `raw_input` over `input`. As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) question, `input` takes the `raw_input` and than performs `eval`, which is generally bad practice and insecure if coming from an untrusted source.

To achieve what you desire while using `raw_input`, you can use the `ast` module

```
import ast

vector = raw_input('Enter Vector:')
vector = list(ast.literal_eval(vector))
print vector

>>> [(4, 4), (2, 5), (1, 6)]
```

Comment: i just noticed if I enter only one tuple like (3,6) vector becomes [3,6] 
but I need [(3,6)] as the output
if I enter 2 like for example (3,6),(4,7) I get [(3,6),(4,7)] how could I get the first one in this format? [(3,6)] ?